# Rank(AB)=Rank(B) iff B(AB)^−AB=B, where ^- means Generalized inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that if $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}, \boldsymbol{B} \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times q}$, then
$$A B(A B)^{-} A=A \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \operatorname{rank}(A B)=\operatorname{rank}(A)$$
$$B(A B)^{-} A B=B \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \operatorname{rank}(A B)=\operatorname{rank}(B)$$

Now I already know how to prove the first line, but how to deal with the second?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any two matrices $M$ and $N$, $\mathcal{C}(MN)\subseteq\mathcal{C}(M)$.

Hence $\mathcal{C}(MM^-)\subseteq\mathcal{C}(M)$. However $\mathrm{rank}(MM^-)\ge\mathrm{rank}(MM^-M)=\mathrm{rank}(M)\ge\mathrm{rank}(MM^-)$. Hence $\mathrm{rank}(M)=\mathrm{rank}(MM^-)$. So we have $\mathcal{C}(MM^-)=\mathcal{C}(M)$.

Also $(MM^-)^2=(MM^-M)M^-=MM^-$. Hence $MM^-$ is idempotent.

So we have proved that for any matrix $MM^-$ is the projector matrix onto the space $\mathcal{C}(M)$

Thus $AB(AB)^-A=A$, implies that all the column vectors of $A$ belong to $\mathcal{C}(AB)$, and hence $\mathcal{C}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{C}(AB)\subseteq\mathcal{C}(A)$. Hence we have $\mathcal{C}(A)=\mathcal{C}(AB)$. Thus $\mathrm{rank}(AB)=\mathrm{rank}(A)$.

Also $\mathrm{rank}(AB)=\mathrm{rank}(A)\implies \mathcal{C}(A)=\mathcal{C}(AB)$. So the column vectors of $A$ indeed belong to $\mathcal{C}(AB)$ and we should have $AB(AB)^-A=A$.

> **Explanation:** Firstly we know that $\mathcal{C}(AB)\subseteq\mathcal{C}(A)$. Dimension of $\mathcal{C}(AB)$ is $\mathrm{rank}(AB)$, while dimension of $\mathcal{C}(A)$ is $\mathrm{rank}(A)$. Thus $\mathrm{rank}(AB)=\mathrm{rank}(A)$, implies the spaces $\mathcal{C}(AB)$ and $\mathcal{C}(A)$ are the same. This is because if $W$ is a subspace of $V$ and $\sim W=\dim V$, then $W=V$.

> Also if $P$ is a projector onto the space $\mathcal{S}$, then for any
> $v\in\mathcal{S}$, we have $Pv=v$.

> We have already proved that $AB(AB)^-$ is a projector onto the column
> space of $AB$, which is same as column space of $A$. Now the column
> space of $A$ contains the columns of $A$, because it is the space
> spanned by the columns of $A$. Hence columns of $A$ belong to
> $\mathcal{C}(AB)$. Since $AB(AB)^-$ is the projector onto the space
> $\mathcal{C}(AB)$, hence for every column of $A$, $AB(AB)^-A_i=A_i$,
> where $A_i$ is the $i^{th}$ column of $A$. Hence $$\big[AB(AB)^-A_1\mid AB(AB)^-A_2\mid\cdots\mid AB(AB)^-A_n\big]=\big[A_1\mid A_2\mid \cdots\mid A_n\big]$$ or $AB(AB)^-A=A$.

Comment: Thanks! But what I want more is to know how the second line proves, :) Where $B(A B)^{-} A B=B \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \operatorname{rank}(A B)=\operatorname{rank}(B)$

Comment: Just use row space instead of column space...use $\mathcal{R}(MN)\subseteq\mathcal{R}(N)$ and that $(AB)^-AB$ is the projector onto $\mathcal{R}(AB)$

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I would be more grateful if you can prove it in more detail, especially the proof from right to left. I am not very able to draw a conclusion directly from what you wrote : Also $\operatorname{rank}(A B)=\operatorname{rank}(A) \Longrightarrow \mathcal{C}(A)=\mathcal{C}(A B) .$ So the column vectors of $A$ indeed belong to$\mathcal{C}(A B)$ and we should have $A B(A B)^{-} A=A$. I am very new to the Matrix Analysis, thank you very much!

Comment: I gave an explanation inside the answer, because it was too long to put in a  comment.